# Trigger event each time input values change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a form and each time the user changes an input field that has a class that starts with "js-input-", I want the value of the corresponding field on the confirmation page (where the user confirms all the values they inputted) to change to the new inputted value.

For some reason, the change event is failing to trigger...

Here's a very simplified test version. I can include more of the html if need be, but I'm pretty sure the issue is in the jQuery here since other change events are working on the same input fields.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      ...
      $("div[class^='js-input-']").change(testEvent);
      ...
  })
    function testEvent() {
    $('.js-input-price').val(Math.random();
}

 <input id="" class="propertyownership propAddress js-input-address" type="text" value="" name=""/>
```

Comment: and you're missing a parentheses after the `random()` call

Comment: Your selector is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"div[class^='js-input-']"` selector has 2 problems:

1. It selects `div` elements not `input` elements. Probably you want to select the input descendants of `div` element. So you should put space between the tag selector and attribute selector.
2. The class attribute doesn't start with `js-input`, it starts with `propertyownership` so your selector doesn't return any element. You can use the attribute contains selector instead: `"input[class*='js-input-']"`

Apart from these there is a syntax error in your code. missing `)` for closing the `val` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your .val()

```
function testEvent() {
    $('.js-input-price').val(Math.random());
}
```

Not sure if that's the fix but it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute selectors test the whole attribute string.. So you need to either set the `js-input-` class to be the first one, or change the selector to match it anywhere inside the attribute

```
$('input[class*="js-input-"]')
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, your element is an `input` but your selector targets `div` elements. And you are missing the final `)`  in `.val(Math.random());`